# Multiple JSON responses to one request

Tags: go

A wrong `uid` is passed to the server : `1`

The following code returns 3 JSON responses for a single request.

As far as my understanding goes, as soon as the Response is written to the ResponseWriter its done; this doesn't appear to be true.

Where do I read more about this and what's the exact issue I am tackling here?

```golang
func getJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    job_id := vars["job_id"]
    var job job
    
    // basic validation for UUID job_id
    uid, err := uuid.FromString(job_id)

    fmt.Println(uid)
    fmt.Println(err)

    if _, err := uuid.FromString(job_id); err != nil {
        sendErrorResponse(w, "Invalid job id "+job_id, err)
    }

    if result := db.Where("job_id = ?", uid).First(&job); result.Error != nil {
        sendErrorResponse(w, "Error retrieving job with "+job_id, result.Error)
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(job)
}


func sendErrorResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, message string, err error) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{Message: message, Error: err.Error()}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Here's the output in Postman :

```json
{
    "Message": "Invalid job id 1",
    "Error": "uuid: incorrect UUID length: 1"
}
{
    "Message": "Error retrieving job with 1",
    "Error": "record not found"
}
{
    "ID": 0,
    "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "application": "",
    "status": "",
    "worker": "",
    "job_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Q: "as soon as the Response is written to the ResponseWriter it's done".  A: Yes.  And you're writing three different strings to the same response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All writes to the http.ResponseWriter are written to the response body transmitted over the network.  The response is completed when the handler returns to the net/http server.

Add return statements to fix the problem.

```
if _, err := uuid.FromString(job_id); err != nil {
    sendErrorResponse(w, "Invalid job id "+job_id, err)
    return
}

if result := db.Where("job_id = ?", uid).First(&job); result.Error != nil {
    sendErrorResponse(w, "Error retrieving job with "+job_id,  result.Error)
    return
}
```